# How to get a Selecteditem from a dropdownlist in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

So I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("EventId", String.Empty)   
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Events)
        @Html.ActionLink(null, "AddEvent", "OtherMeeting", new { eventId = ??)  
</div>
```

At the "??" I wish to get the selected value, only I have no idea how to get the selected value since the list isn't defined in a variable, nor do I seem to be able to give it a name property or something similar to get to the list itself.

Comment: If you need to get this value directly from your view use javascript/jquery. If you need to pass it to your method in your controller - add a parameter to the method - string EventId.

Comment: I need to get it directly from my view, only I have no experience with jquery whatsoever so I'd prefer not to use that if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(null, "AddEvent", "OtherMeeting", new { eventId = ??)
At the "??" I wish to get the selected value
```

Not possible since `ActionLink` happens on the server side and changing your dropdown happens on the client-side. There's a workaround but I like to answer your next issue first:

> nor do I seem to be able to give it a name property or something
>   similar to get to the list itself

When you do a `@Html.DropDownList("EventId")` the razor engine will give it both a `name` and an `id` and both will have the same value and that is `EventId`. You can use that `id` for whatever suit your puspose. The markup that will be written will look like this:

```
<select id="EventId" name="EventId">
```

A couple of things first before we solve your issue:

1. You need to assign a seletlist to the `DropDownList("EventId")`
2. You don't have a link text on `ActionLink`?

Now to solve your issue, you need to change your `ActionLink` to the following, giving it an id (and a text which is optional but make sense to have)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Event", "AddEvent", "OtherMeeting", new { id="eventLink" })
```

Then rebuild your action link, now an `a` tag in jquery everytime a selection is changed:

```
$("#EventId").change(function () {
    $("#eventLink").attr(
        'href',
        '@Url.Action("AddEvent","OtherMeeting")/' + $(this).val()
        );
});
```

Comment: 1. I did assign a selectlist to the dropdownlist, only I didn't show it here, I made it in the controller. 
2. No it's supposed to have no text since I'm going to give it a layout with css later. 

Thankyou for clarifying the ActionLink name and id properties, I didn't know that. Thought I don't really see what I'm supposed to do with the javascript, I have absolutely no experience with this, I don't even know where to put these lines of code to be honest.

Comment: Best practice dictates that scripts should be put before the end of the body tag, that is not even ASP.Net. You should have something like: `<body><script>this is where you will put my js answer</script></body>`. That is not ideal because you might have other pages with an element with an id of `EventId`. But that's the easiest way to explain it. You might want to [read this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344292/ASP-NET-MVC3-Razor-With-jQuery-For-Beginners) to help you get started with MVC+jquery.

Comment: Allright thanks, I will do that, since I suspect I'll be needing more of it later :)